# Is it possible to aggregate the results from different rows into just one, along with the count?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I've got a small DB that has like subsections that come under a single section. Unfortunately, the DB doesn't have a "section" column and just the subsections and they have a "Inventory" column that has either "Computer" or "Laptop" in it. I've made a query that at the very least provides me with the total count of each of these "Inventory" column against each subsection.

However, I'm trying to combine the subsections into a single row and the total count of those subsections alongside it as well. Example of what I'm trying to say:

| subsections | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| a_subsec1 | comp |
| a_subsec1 | comp |
| a_subsec2 | lap |
| a_subsec2 | comp |
| a_subsec3 | lap |
| a_subsec3 | comp |

What I'm currently getting:

| d_sub | inv_count_comp |
| --- | --- |
| a_subsec1 | 2 |
| a_subsec2 | 1 |
| a_subsec3 | 1 |

What I **WANT** to get:

| D_SUB | total_comp_count |
| --- | --- |
| a_sec | 4 |

Here's the query that I'm currently running to get that second table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "subsections", COUNT("inventory") FROM mytable WHERE "inventory" = 'comp' GROUP BY "subsections" ORDER BY "subsections" ASC
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substring the column then you can treat all the row as same subsection.

```
with tb as(
select 'a_subsec1' sec,'comp' inv 
union all
select 'a_subsec1' sec,'comp' inv 
union all
select 'a_subsec2' sec,'lap' inv 
union all
select 'a_subsec2' sec,'comp' inv 
union all
select 'a_subsec3' sec,'lap' inv 
union all
select 'a_subsec3' sec,'comp' inv 

)
select msec,sum(inv_comp) total from(
       select concat(substr(sec,1,1),'_sec') as msec,
       case when inv='comp' then 1 else 0 end as inv_comp,
       tb.* 
       from tb) z
group by msec
```

this query might not be the one you want without some modify but main idea is same.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c050c7d6fbc4e3b7f0e4fe6892bb0e0)

Comment: This works! Thank you, however I just need some clarification on this part: ```(substr(sec,1,1),'_sec')```. As you might have guessed, all the subsections in a single section in my DB start with the exact same characters and only change after like 4-5 characters, so when I use your code as ```(substr(sec,1,5),'_sec')``` it splits it on that character count and shows split counts as well. Works just as how I want it when I use it the way you did, but what's the logic behind it and how does it work this way?

Thank you again!

Comment: `substr` will extract the string you want, and the last `'_sec'` is use with `concat` that basically just make the extract part `a` and `_sec` combine together like `a + _sec = a_sec`

Comment: so if you don't really need to modify your column into `a_sec` instead fine with something like `a_subsec` etc, then you can just remove `concat` function.

Comment: Well, removing the concat function and using ```select sec as msec``` just gives the same result as my query in the question. So the ```concat``` func is an integral part to make this work, however, I just noticed that some subsections in one section do contain the same first 2-3 characters as the subsections in another section so it just concats them into a single field, giving inaccurate results obviously. But I guess that's something I'll have to fix one way or another.

Comment: `concat` is just sting combiner, is the `substr` part make this work.

Comment: Yes, I meant ```substr```, sorry.